# CakePHP 3 Display Colleges owned by Admins

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables colleges and college_admins. Each College is owned by a CollegeAdmin who is a User. I'm using the Auth component to authorize access to which pages can be viewed by which user.

Now, I want to each CollegeAdmin to list only Colleges owned by him / her.

This is what I'm doing in the CollegesController:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->set('colleges', $this->paginate($this->Colleges->ownedBy($this->Auth->user('id'))));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['colleges']);
}
```

And this is the code I'm using in the CollegesTable:

```
public function ownedBy($userId)
{
    $college_admins = TableRegistry::get('CollegeAdmins');

    return $college_admins->find()
            ->select($college_admins->Colleges)
            ->leftJoinWith('Colleges')
            ->where(['CollegeAdmins.user_id' => $userId]);
}
```

But it's not working. It's showing the number of rows / records correctly, but the fields are being displayed as blank. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem. I was doing it the wrong way round in the Colleges table. This code works perfectly:

```
public function ownedBy($userId)
{
    return $this->find()
            ->leftJoinWith('CollegeAdmins')
            ->where(['CollegeAdmins.user_id' => $userId]);
}
```